# Jquery table search and row highlight

Tags: jquery

I'm running into some trouble. I have a table that is created by PHP that pulls data from an Excel file. What I want to do is have the user be able to search certain columns(user specifies column) for a value(also user specified), and if specified value exists, highlight the entire row.

I'm been doing the homework and havent been able to find a suiteable soulute. Here is the code associated with my nightmare (:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        var searchText;

        if(col == 0 || col == 1 || col ==3){
            searchText = $("#searchText").val()
        }
        else if(col == 6){
            searchText = $("#maxPets option:selected").text();
        }
        else if(col == 7){
            searchText = $("#maxWeight option:selected").text();
        }

        $("myTable tr td:nth-child(" + col +")").each(function () {

            if ($(this).val.indexOf(searchText) !=-1) {
                tr.addClass('result');  }
            else {
                tr.removeClass('result');
                }

        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Where does the `col` variable come from?

Comment: http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Comment: The col variable comes from a dropdown select. it is an integer that corresponds which column to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").click(function(){
        var searchText;
        $("tr").removeClass("result");
        if (col == 0 || col == 1 || col == 3) {
            searchText = $("#searchText").val();
        }
        else if(col == 6){
            searchText = $("#maxPets option:selected").text();
        }
        else if(col == 7){
            searchText = $("#maxWeight option:selected").text();
        }
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
            return $("td:eq(" + col + ")", this).text() == searchText;
        }).closest("tr").addClass("result");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle DEMO -- Updated for partial search](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/G23xm/3/)

I still don't know where you're getting `col` from. I suppose a dropdown.

Comment: Yes, the col variable comes from a dropdown. It is the index of which column to be searching for. Only that column should be searched for. And it's been driving me insane.

Comment: It's now restricted to searching only that column to see if the `.text()` matches.

Comment: That looks a lot better. I'm not really up with jquery much. It's still not highlighting the row. Also, does that search for a direct match or a partial match.. like will er highlight the row that contains "Aerie on Tanque Verde?" Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's a complete match only. I just added a jsFiddle demo so you can see it working in action. Feel free to add your `maxPets` and `maxWeight` dropdowns and give it a test.

Comment: To do a partial match I would change the return to $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
            return $("td:eq(" + col + ")", this).text().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        }).closest("tr").addClass("result");  correct?

Comment: That sounds correct, yes. Give it a try in the fiddle and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
        if ($(this).val.indexOf(searchText) !=-1) {
            tr.addClass('result');  }
        else {
            tr.removeClass('result');
            }
```

to:

```
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(searchText) !=-1) {
            $(this).closest("tr").addClass('result');  }
        else {
            $(this).closest("tr").removeClass('result');
        }
```

`val` is a jQuery method, which is a function, it's not a string that you can search. And it's the wrong method for what you presumably want -- the contents of a table field is read with `text()` -- `val()` is for the value of a user input.

And there's no variable `tr` -- you want to add/remove the class of the element's containing row.

This can be further simplified to:

```
$(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("result", $(this).text().indexOf(searchText) !=-1);
```